# .NET DevKit SDK Documentation Missing?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I just tried to access the SDK Documentation for the .NET DevKit and the link leads me to what is, essentially, a "Not Found" page.

Where can we find the Docs (you aren't updating them, perhaps to V3, are you)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the link. http://developer.intuit.com/IntuitDataServicesSDK/ 
It contains the NDocs for the SDK.

regards, 
Jarred